# How i can organize function in function in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

As it is not possible in `nodejs` to use variables in required files directly i want to create  one model object through which i would be able to  reach all my models. For example i have something like this:

```
function User() {
    this.get = function () {
        console.log('getSomeUser');
    }
}

function Post() {
    this.send = function () {
        console.log('sendSomePost');
    }
}

module.exports = function Model () {
    this.User = User();

    this.Post = Post();
};
```

Then i require it like and should use like this:

```
var Model = require('model.js');
var model = new Model();
model.User.get();
model.Post.send();
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

This works except your `module.exports` would have to look like:

```
module.exports = function Model () {
    this.User = new User();
    this.Post = new Post();
};
```

`User` and `Post` would need to be instantiated objects in order to use them they way that you are. You may also need to require `model.js` like so:

```
var Model = require('./model.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like this approach better:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var somelib = require('../path/somelib')(app),

    //a 'private' method
    function somethingPrivate(callback){
        callback();
    };

    return {
        User: function (req, res) {
            somethingPrivate();
            console.log('getSomeUser');
        },

        Post: function(req, res) {
            console.log('sendSomePost');
        }
    }
}
```

now note that I am passing (app) into this function.  this is so that if need be I can access app specific things that have already been loaded on init.  It's not required though.

I then call this by doing this somewhere else, say in my controller:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var Model = require('../path/to/Model')(app);
    app.get('/user', Model.User);
}
```

So lets look at this closer, if for example you don't want to pass app along the chain, then just do the following:

```
module.exports = function(){

    //a 'private' method
    function somethingPrivate(callback){
        callback();
    };

    return {
        User: function (req, res) {
            somethingPrivate();
            console.log('getSomeUser');
        },

        Post: function(req, res) {
            console.log('sendSomePost');
        }
    }
}
```

then elsewhere you do:

```
    var Model = require('../path/to/Model');
```